# Crystal Report on VB with a condition

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using visual studio 2010 and mysql for database and crystal report for reporting.

I want to show report and filter it based on its category. I have tried this tutorial here : http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_parameter_string.htm

It works, but only if the parameter already been filled. What I want is, if the parameter empty then report will show all item, else report will show based on the parameter.

How do i do that ?

Here a little detail of my project :

Database field :

- ID
- Category
- Item

Parameter Name in crystal Report :

- fillcategory

Field in visual studio :

- cboCategory [i am using combobox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition in record selection formula..something like below

```
If parameter=""
Then
Category=category
Else
Category=parameter
```

Comment: whenever i debug the form its always ask to enter parameter value, is there any way to just go straight to show the report without needed to input a parameter value ?

Comment: You cany bypass a parameter once used in report...if you want to debug without parameter prompt then remove parameter from report design temperorly and then you can debug